# emulate chroot in perl for Windows

Tags: windows, perl, chroot

I am looking for a solution to have the concept of `chroot` in a perl script that runs on windows as it seems there is no `chroot` in Windows perl ports.

Comment: perhaps http://www.sandboxie.com/

Comment: Thanks for the link. Unfortunately, I cannot install additional software on the computers in question.

Comment: I don't think there is any equivalent concept on Windows platforms. Is it just filesystem access you want to restrict?

Comment: There is no `chroot` in the Windows ports of Perl because there is no support for anything like `chroot` in the OS.  How exactly is Perl supposed to enforce anything of this nature on child processes without the assistance of the OS or a special driver?  If you can't install additional capabilities on the computers in question, you'll just have to do without the capabilities.

Comment: @tjd I hoped that maybe there was a function to which I can pass two paths (`is_underneath($root_path, $desired_open_path)` that would indicate if the following `open` should be made or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given what you've requested in your comment to your question, you may want to look into the `subsumes` method of `Path::Class::Dir` objects.  Other options include `Cwd::Ext::abs_path_is_in()` and `Cwd::realpath()`.

Understand that this is nothing like `chroot` and will have no effect on child processes, string `eval`s or even Modules you load.